# Using Java 1.4 for applet when 1.6 is installed

Tags: java, reflection, applet

My Java applet only supports 1.4 java run time(1). I am having one machine on which both Java 1.4 and 1.6 environment is installed. Is there some setting available by which I can make sure my applet will always use Java 1.4 run time when it runs?

1. We are using key event class private data array `bData` with the help of Java reflection. The data which is there in this array JDK 1.4 and 1.6 is different in both the version.

Comment: What is the reason it does not support a newer JVM?

Comment: In which way does it only support Java 1.4? Because of libraries? Note that compiled Java 1.4 code should run in a Java 6.0 environment, too. Can you provide more specific information?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to create applet that works on 1.4 and not on 1.6. If you have, please edit your question to show specific code that results in the incompatibility.

Comment: I just wondering, if any machine can run different JVM using only one JAVA_HOME. And the problem is not about applet, its common to any java application. Isn't it funny to try something like that?

Comment: I have looked at http://www.coderanch.com/t/385817/java/java/Accessing-private-data-AWTEvent-class example and also use scancode variable. Setting a JAVA_HOME to 1.4 is also not working... We dont want to use JAVA 1.6 for my applet.

Answer (score 1):

A Java application compiled with JDK 1.4 will run on JDK 1.6.

You can compile a Java application with JDK 1.6, but compatible with JDK 1.4 by configuring the 'source level'.

Although you can choose your default JDK to be safe, but it depends on your operating system. If you are on Linux, you can choose between available Java versions using `pdate-alternatives --config java` command (which will modify some symlinks in the hindsight).

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to force a specific installed version to run, but if one Java plugin replaces the other there might be an issue with this. See linked question for further details.

[Force Internet Explorer to use a specific Java Runtime Environment install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254/force-internet-explorer-to-use-a-specific-java-runtime-environment-install)

Are there any issues with running the 1.4 code on 1.6? If not, you should be fine. Just avoid using anything in the classpath that changed significantly between these versions. Otherwise, look [here][1]. The codebase download thing is interesting, since it lets you download a different classpath. So, regardless of the JRE version, you could force the download of a 1.4 JRE classpath, which should ensure full compatability.

**Edit: found an updated guide to using previous classpaths with newer Java versions in applets, which actually seems to work:**

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

Edit 2: I actually have it working, but it appears to need to download JRE 1.4 and install it, but then it will run the applet with it automatically. However, this might be suitable for your needs.

http://www.2shared.com/file/bl3Rua2e/applet.html -- extract the archive, and then run index.html inside this. All source code is included.

Comment: We are using key event class private data array bData with the help of java reflection. And the data which is there in this array JDK 1.4 and 1.6 is different in both the version. We are building our jar file using JDK 1.4. I have restriction to build my jar file on top of 1.4.

Comment: Okay, so use the JRE classpath downloading mechanism as referenced on the linked page :) Then it should work, regardless of the installed JRE.

Comment: I am sorry Chris, I not get your answer.

Comment: The best idea would be to avoid using the private data. It's private for a reason. What is `bData` used for?

Comment: @Chris *"..avoid using the private data."*  +1  Best comment/strategy so far on this thread.

Comment: I need the bData to get the Scancode for the special characters when we are using multiple languages keyboard layout...

Comment: I can't find bData in KeyEvent, after downloading Java 1.4.2 SDK.

Comment: `keyCode`, `keyChar` and `keyLocation` are the only fields, and they are accessible through getter methods.

Comment: Oh, it exists in the superclass, `AWTEvent`, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7:

Control Panel -> Programs -> Java

Select 'Java' tab, and View the Java Runtime Environment settings.
Ensure that your Java 1.4 entry is selected.