# Java 8 and browser plugin

Tags: java, applet, jvm, java-8

I installed JDK 8, when I type in cmd `java -version` I get 1.8, the browser when run my applet which needs Java 1.8, it says the JRE 1.8 is not available, run this using the latest JDK.

When I check the plugin in browser all point to JRE  7, Chrome and IE.  In Java Control Panel I see JDK 8 listed.

Comment: have a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254/force-internet-explorer-to-use-a-specific-java-runtime-environment-install)

Comment: A **JDK** often does not provide a JVM intended to be used as a browser plug-in.  Install ***JRE* 8** and report back.

Comment: JRE is bundled with JDK. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: JDK *used* to be bundled with the Java plugin, because installing the JDK also installs a JRE.

Its right there in the installation options "Public JRE".

Answer (score 8):

I think the likely explanation is that you've installed a 64bit JRE/JDK, but you still have 32bit browsers.

So the browsers just aren't seeing and are unable to use the 64bit plugin.

I had the same issue, and I installed the x86 JDK as well, and subsequently the Java plugin is listed.

[image]

[image]