# Force ie to work with Specific JRE

Tags: java

I had gone through the "Force Internet Explorer to use a specific Java Runtime Environment install?" topic of Daniel Cassidy and i followed exactly the same steps.

But still my IE 8 uses the latest java version and not the old one.

File Versions:
IE - 8
Java - 1.5.0_10 and 1.6.0_25
My Application requires 1.5.0_10 and 1.6.0_25/Java 8 for other browsers.

Steps followed:
1. IE - Tools - Internet Options - Advanced - "Unchecked Java" since i am not able to uncheck the same in Control Panel - Java - Advanced - "default java for browsers'.

2. Navigated to Program Files - Java - jre6 - bin - javacpl.exe - made sure the Java - Advanced - "default java for browsers' - "Microsoft Internet explorer" is unchecked.
3. Then Navigated to Program Files - Java - jre1.5.0_10 - bin - javacpl.exe - made sure the Java - Advanced - "default java for browsers' - "Microsoft Internet explorer" is checked.
4. Now when i open my application, still the IE opens it up with the Java 6 jre.

Please let me know how could i force my IE 8 to open the application with jre1.5.0_10

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Please add a link to that guide that you are referring too. Thanks. Besides that this question might be better suited for the superuser site (http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Are you using a JNLP file to launch your java app?

Comment: Hi Reto,Please find the link below, which i was referring for this issue.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254/force-internet-explorer-to-use-a-specific-java-runtime-environment-install

Comment: Hi PeterK, My Oracle ERP application uses this Java Runtime.

Comment: Friends, any suggestions please....?